# Как получить значение из choices в Django?

Tags: django

Есть файл **models.py**

```
class Languages(models.Model):

    LANGUAGES = (
        ('ru', 'Russian'),
        ('en', 'English'),
    )

    lang = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True, choices=LANGUAGES)
    lang_code = models.CharField(max_length=5, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

И файл **admin.py**

```
class PostLanguage(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'lang_code': ('lang',)}

admin.site.register(Languages, PostLanguage)
```

Допустим в админке добавляю язык *Russian* (поле *lang*), тогда поле *lang_code* заполняется автоматически значением *ru*.

Как можно сделать, чтобы поле *slug* заполнилось автоматически значением *russian*?

И как можно сделать, чтобы в форме тоже отображалось значение *Russian*, а не *ru*?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да [получить-то легко](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display), а вот использовать в качестве значения для `prepopulated_fields` вряд ли выйдет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а в форме (на сайте) тоже нужно использовать get_FOO_display() или в файле forms.py можно как-то настроить отображение?

Comment: В смысле? Это обычный метод, который можно вызвать для любого экземпляра модели в любом месте, где вообще можно совершать вызовы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, на сайте отображаю форму (другой модели, Question). Одно из полей Question имеет ссылку на модель Language и при отображении этого поля выводится первое значение из кортежа (например, "ru"), но нужно вывести "Russian". Это можно как-то реализовать в forms.py или только в шаблоне получится сделать?

Comment: Ссылку? В смысле `ForeignKey`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да через ForeignKey ссылаюсь

Comment: Тогда в `Languages` надо определить метод `__str__` возвращающий нужное значение.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, я, наверное, неправильно выразился. Имелось ввиду, как на сайте в форме (не в админке) выводить информацию второго элемента кортежа? В данном случае выводится, как "ru" тега <select>, а не "Russian" (в вопрос сейчас добавлю изображение)
За метод __str__ спасибо, уже реализовано.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, по видимому, неправильно Вас понял. Действительно нужно было реализовать метод `__str__: self.get_lang_display()` и все правильно отображалось. Спасибо

Comment: Если нужно, чтобы `slug`, автоматически заполнился значением _russian_, то можно переопределить метод _save_ и прописать следующее: `self.lang = slugify(self.lang)`